# iOS get NSInteger from NSIndexpath

Tags: ios, objective-c

Am getting selected cell position from collection view

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"button clicked");


  //  CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero
   //                                        toView: GlossaryCollView];
    NSIndexPath *centerCellIndexPath =
    [self.GlossaryCollView indexPathForItemAtPoint:
     [self.view convertPoint:[self.view center] toView:self.GlossaryCollView]];


    NSLog(@"cell index path :%@",centerCellIndexPath);




}
```

It gives the value nslog =  {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}

From this i need only the path first value.. How can i get it??

I can get last value using this code..

```
NSUInteger lastIndex = [centerCellIndexPath indexAtPosition:[centerCellIndexPath length] - 1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy :)

```
NSInteger row = centerCellIndexPath.row;
NSInteger section = centerCellIndexPath.section;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working answer to get the cell index for the button..

```
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero
                                           toView: self.GlossaryCollView];
    NSIndexPath *tappedIP = [self.GlossaryCollView indexPathForItemAtPoint:buttonPosition];

  NSInteger *rowIndex = tappedIP.row;
```